# Identify year of manufacturing of Merida frame by Serial number

Tags: road-bike

I'm trying to buy a used Merida Scultura Road frame, but the current owner does not know the year of manufacturing. It is possible to extract this information from serial number?

Serial:

WC 93055 B

BI - 1582 BR

[image]

Comment: E-Mail Meridia? If anyone's going to have that info they will.

Comment: Your best bet is to look at the original components, and the archive of products on the merida website and see if you can get a match,  Or, don't care about the year and simply base it on the quality and spec and wear of the components.  Give us a clean, well lit photo of the right side and we can have a guess at its age.

Comment: @ninjaattacksheep, I emailed them, but I did not get any answers. :c

Comment: @Criggie, I added a photo now! For what I researched, it looks like the 2007 model.

Answer (score -1):

Per comments from the OP, looks like a 2007 model.